# Merge tag request

Tags: discussion, tags

There is the [quantitative-easing](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantitative-easing) tag and the [quantative-easing](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantative-easing) tag. The latter is clearly a typo. **Can these be merged please?** That would avoid me spamming the main page with tag edits :)

Comment: Wow, 9 questions with the typo tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this, the merge is done and any attempts to enter the typo tag will now automatically remap into [quantitative-easing](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantitative-easing).